# Does SMAP/SMEP block allocation in userland (kmalloc)?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, exploit

I am trying to exploit a heap overflow in Linux kernel with all the protections enable i.e. SMAP and SMEP. What I understand is that SMEP doesn't allow me to execute userland code and SMAP doesn't allow me to read or write to userland. But I am wondering: if I replace the free list pointer of some free object with some userland pointer, will I be able to allocate the object in userland?

Also I tried replacing the free list pointer but I am getting weird crashes which I am not able to debug properly. I am not sure are they because of me trying to allocate something in userland.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SMAP / SMEP are mitigations that are implemented at the hardware level. If enabled, the CPU generates an exception on invalid memory accesses that is then caught by the registered kernel exception handler which will either panic, kill the current process or do whatever else is needed. It doesn't matter if the invalid access comes from a free list pointer or from something else. Kernel heap pointers are not some "special" kind of pointers that would allow you to bypass SMAP.

The only way in which something like what you describe can work is if for whatever reason, at the point of read/write to an user space address, SMAP is disabled. For example, if you manage to corrupt a pointer that is then used in an execution path that does: SMAP OFF → R/W → SMAP ON. Thing is, you don't usually find such a usage, because something like this is only done when the kernel *knows* it needs to handle an user pointer (e.g. `copy_{to,from}_user()`). Any other instance of temporarily disabling SMAP and then using a pointer should essentially be considered a bug.

So no, you will not be able to allocate a kernel object in user space, unless it's some really buggy kernel module that you're trying to exploit which wrongly disables SMAP when it's not needed.